# Variant of Quotient Metric is an Ultrametric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces, ultrametric

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$.  Then
$$
d'([x],[y]):= \inf\{d(x',y'): x' \in [x],\, y' \in [y]\},
$$
may fail the triangle inequality, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x\in X$ under $\sim$ (and similarly for $[y]$).  However, does $d'$ define an ultrametric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it can *also* fail to be a metric at all, as two distinct classes can have $d'$-distance $0$.

Also, it need not be an ultrametric (trivial example: start with a non-ultrametric $d$, and have trivial classes..).